# Ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/bizmeb/public_html/index.php on line 21

Tags: php

Выдает ошибку сайт

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/bizmeb/public_html/index.php on line 21
```

Вот код:

```
<?
@error_reporting(0);
$user_agent_to_filter = array( '#Ask\s*Jeeves#i', '#HP\s*Web\s*PrintSmart#i', '#HTTrack#i', '#IDBot#i', '#Indy\s*Library#',
'#ListChecker#i', '#MSIECrawler#i', '#NetCache#i', '#Nutch#i', '#RPT-HTTPClient#i',
'#rulinki\.ru#i', '#Twiceler#i', '#WebAlta#i', '#Webster\s*Pro#i','#www\.cys\.ru#i',
'#Wysigot#i', '#Yahoo!\s*Slurp#i', '#Yeti#i', '#Accoona#i', '#CazoodleBot#i',
'#CFNetwork#i', '#ConveraCrawler#i','#DISCo#i', '#Download\s*Master#i', '#FAST\s*MetaWeb\s*Crawler#i',
'#Flexum\s*spider#i', '#Gigabot#i', '#HTMLParser#i', '#ia_archiver#i', '#ichiro#i',
'#IRLbot#i', '#Java#i', '#km\.ru\s*bot#i', '#kmSearchBot#i', '#libwww-perl#i',
'#Lupa\.ru#i', '#LWP::Simple#i', '#lwp-trivial#i', '#Missigua#i', '#MJ12bot#i',
'#msnbot#i', '#msnbot-media#i', '#Offline\s*Explorer#i', '#OmniExplorer_Bot#i',
'#PEAR#i', '#psbot#i', '#Python#i', '#rulinki\.ru#i', '#SMILE#i',
'#Speedy#i', '#Teleport\s*Pro#i', '#TurtleScanner#i', '#User-Agent#i', '#voyager#i',
'#Webalta#i', '#WebCopier#i', '#WebData#i', '#WebZIP#i', '#Wget#i',
'#Yandex#i', '#Yanga#i', '#Yeti#i','#msnbot#i',
'#spider#i', '#yahoo#i', '#jeeves#i' ,'#google#i' ,'#Googlebot#i' ,'#altavista#i',
'#scooter#i' ,'#av\s*fetch#i' ,'#asterias#i' ,'#spiderthread revision#i' ,'#sqworm#i',
'#ask#i' ,'#lycos.spider#i' ,'#infoseek sidewinder#i' ,'#ultraseek#i' ,'#polybot#i',
'#webcrawler#i', '#robozill#i', '#gulliver#i', '#architextspider#i', '#yahoo!\s*slurp#i',
'#charlotte#i', '#ngb#i' ) ;
<?
stop_ips_masks = array( 
"66\.249\.[6-9][0-9]\.[0-9]+", 
"74\.125\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", 
"65\.5[2-5]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", 
"74\.6\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", 
"67\.195\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", 
"72\.30\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", 
"38\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", 
"93\.172\.94\.227", 
"212\.100\.250\.218", 
"71\.165\.223\.134", 
"70\.91\.180\.25", 
array("65\.93\.62\.242",... etc
```

Answer (score 3):

В вашей ошибке содержится весь ответ на ващш вопрос

```
20 '#charlotte#i', '#ngb#i' ) ;
21 <?
22 stop_ips_masks = array(
```

На строке 21 открывается тег php, в то время как предыдущий закрыт не был

Answer (score 1):

Вместо <? лучше используйте <?php, на ошибку вам указал [@Fike](/users/16095/fike), удалите <? в 21 строке или замените на ?> (что более подходит вашему коду). И еще одна рекомендация: если файл содержит только php код, то лучше не использовать закрывающий php-тег в конце файла (?>).